# Is it usually possible to transfer credits for graduate courses completed during an undergrad degree in the US?

Tags: united-states, coursework

I'm currently an undergraduate student planning out my coursework for the next couple of semesters, and I wanted to ask if taking graduate courses as an undergrad allows them to be transferred to a PhD program. These graduate courses are not used to satisfy any requirement for my undergrad degree but would just be extra courses that I'm interested in taking.

I understand that different graduate programs have different rules on transferring credits, but to give a specific example, in UIUC's graduate school handbook, [they say](https://grad.illinois.edu/sites/grad.illinois.edu/files/pdfs/handbook.pdf#transfer-credit):

> Graduate students may request to transfer credit earned from another institution to be counted toward a graduate degree. This is generally limited to a maximum of 12 semester hours. Credit that can be transferred must be graduate level credit that meets the following additional criteria:
>
> - that has not previously been applied toward a degree or other
>   transcripted credential,
> - that is graded graduate-level credit from an    accredited
>   institution, and
> - for which the student has achieved a    grade of B or better, or
>   received a Satisfactory grade in the case of    a
>   Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory grading mode.*

I don't think these requirements are particularly unique; from what I've read, there's at least a few schools that have requirements similar to this.

Suppose I take a graduate course...

- that does not count towards any requirement for my undergrad degree
- that is graded (not audited)
- in which I receive an A

Would I then have a decent chance of transferring that course?

Comment: That depends entirely, as you seem to recognize, on the policies of the accepting institution and has no general answer.  It isn't something to lose sleep over, though. If the courses appeal to you and you can do them, then why not? They probably make acceptance more likely in any case if you do well.

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: in the U.S., in math, I don't think transfer-or-not of credits for basic grad courses is any sort of substantive issue. Don't worry about it. Very often, you can "test out" of basic grad requirements... or, at worst, find that "required courses" are easy if you have a great background. "Credits" don't have much to do with getting a PhD...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the UIUC policy is fairly typical, some low limit. And it is also a "request," not something automatic. In my program, we could actually only possibly waive the first year stats sequence (so like 6 credits), not the substantive courses.

I would not plan your courses with the goal to shave time off your PhD program. It is probably more likely to not happen than to work. Even if you can't waive the courses, they'll be easier.